# Cuando los pasaportes se expidan a menores o incapacitados ... las personas o instituciones que tuvieran asignada su patria potestad o tutela

Tags: significado-en-contexto

¿se puede substituir "expidan" por "expiden", y substituir "tuvieran" por "tienen" en el siguiente párrafo? Si la respuesta es un "sí", ¿cual es la diferencia de significado entre "expidan" y "expiden"? ¿Y la diferencia de significado" entre "tuvieran" y "tienen"? ¡Muchas gracias!

"[Cuando los pasaportes se expidan a menores o incapacitados, la validez señalada podrá ser limitada a petición motivada de las personas o instituciones que tuvieran asignada su patria potestad o tutela.](https://administracion.gob.es/pag_Home/Tu-espacio-europeo/derechos-obligaciones/ciudadanos/viajes/documentos/pasaportes-caducados.html)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El subjuntivo normalmente se utiliza en textos jurídicos para expresar deseos, posibilidades, órdenes y describir situaciones que aún no han llegado a ocurrir. En ocasiones su utilización puede parecer arcaica, ambigua o poco clara.

> "Cuando los pasaportes se **expidan** a menores o incapacitados, la
> validez señalada podrá ser limitada a petición motivada de las
> personas o instituciones que **tuvieran** asignada su patria potestad
> o tutela."

**Expidan** y **tuvieran** son verbos que se utilizan aquí anticipándose al encuentro de que aparezcan determinadas "posibilidades" o "circunstancias" para el caso de quien tenga o tengan fijada por ley la patria potestad o tutela de menores o los incapacitados.

Legislativamente el modo subjuntivo se usa por tradición y para entender y expresar mejor lo que el jurista desea decir.

Si bien en el lenguaje común sería posible expresarse con "expiden" o "tienen", jurídicamente se expresan en subjuntivo "**expidan**"  ya que encaja mejor con el conjunto amplio de posibilidades grupos de personas que pueden existir, así pudieran darse entre aquel o aquellos que tienen fijada la potestad o tutela, personas que pueden tener pasaporte, menores, incapacitados, mayores de edad, doble nacionalidad, personas que tiene la tutela compartida, o la potestad del incapacitado en solo un apartado...

Si lo expresas en presente de indicativo "**expiden**" o "**tienen**" por una parte suena en modo exhortativo y por otro invalidaría de algún modo la cantidad de circunstancias o distintos casos que se pueden presentar en la ley a la hora de asignar la patria potestad o evaluar las diferentes formas de tutela, algo que si te brinda el uso del "subjuntivo" al fijar dentro de las palabras "expidan" o "tuvieran", un número amplio de posibilidades.

Comment: ¡ Muchas gracias por su respuesta, Diego! Se lo agradezco mucho 